# Dependencies of my RCP application are missing on my update site

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, p2, update-site

I am creating an RCP application. I am planning to provide p2 update functionality.

For example there are 4 plugins: A,B,C,D

Plugin A and B represents the core functionality of my RCP application. I have created a feature with name com.myorg.feature.core. In-side the feature.xml, in the plugin tab I have added plugins A & B.

I am adding feature com.myorg.feature.core as a dependecy in the product file of my RCP applicaton. After that I export the RCP application using product file (here product is a feature based product).

Now I have created two more features.

```
com.myorg.feature.featureC
com.myorg.feature.featureD
```

As these are optional functionalities to my RCP application, I want user to chose, whether to install them or not. So user will chose the install new software option where this features will be list.

The problem I am facing is, these plugins C & D are using certain 3rd party libraries e.g. BIRT, NATTABLE. So each time, I build featureC or featureD, put it on the update site and I try to install them in my application, they show the dependency failures, like `bundle missing: org.eclipse.birt.core`

I go back to the feature.xml for featureC -> plugins tab -> add org.eclipse.birt.core and build feature again. But several times my RCP application failed to install with errors bundles missing.

Is there any mechanism where I can determine all the required bundle from start? Is is the right way to launch updates or new install-able units for my RCP application?

Comment: "But several times my RCP application failed to install with errors bundles missing" - can you be more concrete? What errors do you get then?

Comment: it says, bundle missing and cannot proceed ahead with installation of featureC.. so i have to go to feature.xml for C add the missing bundle and release it again. But isn't there any way eclipse can calculate it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the first question should be if you really want to use the Eclipse PDE export wizards for delivering updates.

Instead, you should set up a headless build for your project. If you are familiar with the PDE (and don't happen to hate Maven ;-), [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) is probably the right choice for you. (Disclaimer: I'm committer on the Tycho project, and may not know all potential alternatives.)

You can easily make Tycho include all the transitive dependencies in a [p2 repository](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-repository): Just set the option `includeAllDependencies` to `true` on the [tycho-p2-repository-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-repository-plugin/assemble-repository-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

@Priank it is better to add all dependencies in plugins tab in feature.xml, this is only one time effort. You can compute required plugins from dependencies tab of feature.xml